# raphael.js FreeTransform Bounding Box to large

Tags: raphael

Im creating a paper.text element, then I am using a function to arc the text along a given path.
http://pastebin.com/gLq0baw1
The problem i am having is the free transform bounding box applied to the paper.set is  WAY TO BIG http://gyazo.com/795e08faa01af696d0a35a36ec1db32b.png

the text is the only thing inside the set yet the bounding box is absolutely massive.  Any ideas whats corrupting the size?

Comment: Can you demonstrate this in a Fiddle? http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: Not easily Elbert its coded into a shopping cart =/